# Trying to use the method from one class(bike) to implement in my second class( dockingstation)

Tags: ruby, error-handling, rspec

```
   class DockingStation
  
  attr_reader :bikes, :capacity
  attr_accessor :capacity
  
  DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 20
  
 def initialize(capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY)
   @bikes = []  
   @capacity = capacity
 end
 

 
  def release_bike
    fail 'No bikes available' if empty?
    @bikes
  end
  
  def dock(bike)
    fail 'bike full' if full?
    @bikes << bike
  end
  
  def full?
    @bikes.count >= DEFAULT_CAPACITY
  end
  
  def empty?
    @bikes.empty?
  end
  

  private :full? , :empty? 
  
end
 class Bike
    def working?
        true
      end
      def report_broken
         @broken = true
      end
      def broken?
        @broken
      end
    end
    require './lib/docking_station.rb'
    require './lib/bike.rb'
    describe DockingStation  do
        describe 'initialization' do
            subject{DockingStation.new}
            let(:bike) {Bike.new}
            it 'default capacity' do 
                described_class::DEFAULT_CAPACITY.times do
                    subject.dock(bike) 
                end
                expect{ subject.dock(bike) }.to raise_error 'bike full'
             end
        end    
        it 'has a default capacity' do
        expect(subject.capacity).to eq DockingStation::DEFAULT_CAPACITY
      end
         describe '#release_bike' do
            it 'releases a bike' do
                 bike = Bike.new
```

I want my rspec test to pass( down below) but I keep getting the error that nothing was raised. My goal is for my station to not release a broken bike that was reported when docked but the method broken? is in my bike file and so I can't in my method write 'fail 'bike broken' if broken? as the docking station file doesn't recognise the method. Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated

```
it 'raises an error if bike is broken' do
           bike = Bike.new
           bike.report_broken
           subject.dock bike
           expect {subject.release_bike}.to raise_error 'No bikes available'
        end
```

Comment: The test expects the `DockingStation` to raise an error if there is only a broken bike at the station. That means if your test doesn't pass then the problem is in your `DockingStation` class. What does that class look like?

Comment: spickermann, I have edited it to show my docking station class. I am unsure where to raise the error in my docking station class

Answer (score 0):

Your test looks like it should raise an error if there are no bikes in a docking station or only broken bikes.

```
it 'raises an error if bike is broken' do
  bike = Bike.new
  bike.report_broken
  subject.dock bike
  expect {subject.release_bike}.to raise_error 'No bikes available'
end
```

But your `release_bike` method currently doesn't take broken bikes into account:

```
def release_bike
  fail 'No bikes available' if empty?
  @bikes
end
```

I guess your test should pass if you change that method to the following:

```
def release_bike
  available_bikes = @bikes.select { |bike| !bike.broken? }
  fail 'No bikes available' if available_bikes.empty?
  available_bikes
end
```

Which first selects all bikes from the `@bikes` array that are not broken and then checks only for if there are non-broken bikes available.

Comment: Thank you Spickermann for taking the time to help. This has helped clarify an issue I have been having

Comment: @hibscodes: You are welcome. Please consider upvoting an answer if it was helpful and accepting it when it solved your issue. This is a way to say thank you and to indicate to others that your problem is solved.